# If a function $f$ is multiplicative, how do I show that $\sum_{d\mid n} \mu(n/d) f(d)$ is also multiplicative?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function

I am studying *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* by Ireland and Rosen, and this is exercise 9 from chapter 2.

The authors define a function $f$ to be multiplicative if for all $a, b$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$, $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$.

The exercise is to show that given a multiplicative function $f$, we can construct another function $$h(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(n/d) f(d)$$

How do I show that this function is multiplicative? $\mu$ is the [Mobius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function#Definition). Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've never used Ireland and Rosen, do they do Dirichlet series alongside multiplicative functions, or are you just given them from scratch?

Comment: We have some basic questions about Dirichlet series later in the same chapter but I think this exercise is supposed to be done without them? Not sure ...

Answer (score 2):

More generally, suppose that $g$ is another multiplicative function. You want to see that $$F(n)=\sum_{ab\mid n}f(a)g(b)$$ is multiplicative.
The key is to see how the set of divisors $ab\mid mn$ partition when $(m,n)=1$. After that, it should be cake. Good luck.

Comment: If $ab \mid mn$ and $(m,n) = 1$, then $ab$ has an "m" part and an "n" part and these parts are relatively prime. In other words, there exists $x,y$ such that $xy =ab$, $x|m$, and $x|n$. Is this what you meant by partitioning? If so, I don't really see what to do next :(

Comment: @TerrenceTown That's the idea. Scrutinize it. =)

Comment: Okay so we split each of $a$ and $b$ into their $m$ and $n$ parts (call them $a_m,a_n,b_m,b_n$, and since $\gcd(a_m,a_n)=\gcd(b_m,b_n)=1$, we get $$F(mn) = \sum_{ab \mid mn} f(a)g(b) = \sum_{ab \mid mn} f(a_m)f(a_n)g(b_m)g(b_n)$$

I want this to equal $F(m)F(n)$ but there must be some obvious way to separate the sum ...